# component.find throwing error when component is created conditionally in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-if

I have the following code in my component

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! not(empty(v.assignedto)) }"> 
                                        <lightning:input aura:id="assignedToInput" value="{#v.assignedto.value}"  label=""/>
                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                        <lightning:input aura:id="assignedToInput" value=""  class="slds-hide" label=""/>
                                    </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
```

The following is the helper code

```
getAccountRequestListHelper : function(component,event,helper){
        console.log('inside get account list helper'+component.get("v.ucn"));

        var action = component.get("c.searchAccounts");
        console.log('Here 1');
        var assignedToId = component.find("assignedToInput1").get('v.value');
        console.log('Here 2'+assignedToId);
        console.log('assignedToInput'+assignedToId);
        .
        .
        .
```

here I am getting an error in line

```
var assignedToId = component.find("assignedToInput").get('v.value');
```

when assignedToInput1 is not populated in the component. The assignedToInput1 value is conditional. It will not always be populated. can anyone tell me how to get over this issue

Comment: did you create a [duplicate account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/43183/rimii) by mistake?

Comment: I did. i am not being able to log in to my previous. Is there any way I can get it back?

Comment: Moderators cannot merge accounts. You have to [reach out to the CM team](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would avoid invoking `get` on an undefined value:

```
var input = component.find("assignedToInput1");
var assignedToId = input ? input.get('v.value') : null;
```